# MongoDB - How I can fetch data based on different criterias

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am storing users social media data in mongo db. I have users collection which contains all the user documents. In user document I want to store all the pages he has liked in Sports category. I am storing an array of all the pages he has liked with key as 'Sports' in user document.
If I want to get all the users who have liked a particular Sports page e.g. Sachin Tendulkar, I can retrieve this using find() in mongoDB but it will have search through millions of user documents to get the result. This will impact on performance.

Sample schema:

```js
{
    name: "XYZ",
    Bday: "07/25/1990",
    email: "xyz@yahoo.com",
    location: "India",
    gender: "male",
    Sports: ["Sachin Tendulkar", "John Cena", "Federer", "Nadal", "Ronaldo",....]
}
```

What exactly I want:

I want to store data such that I can get information based on different criterias (view). Consider a cube. One side of the cube gives me data based on User, another side gives me info based on categories and so on.
How to achieve this with MongoDB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider your question. It skirts dangerously close to asking for recommendations of tools or products at this point, which will not be viewed favorably. Try to make it more specific about solving your data analysis problem and then you will likely get some help.

Comment: One more suggestion. Try some sample data to illustrate. Even a small sample. Programmers love data to solve problems by.

Comment: Your description of your document schema is hard to follow. Can you please post an example document?

Comment: I have added the sample of document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to consider.

- Indexing: for each criteria (view) you need to create index. For example, the following two indexes illustrate two possible queries:

  `db.users.ensureIndex({Sports:1});`

This will create index on `Sports` and therefore all queries that include `Sports` will be fast: `db.users.find({Sports:"Sachin Tendulkar"});`

```
db.users.ensureIndex({location:1});
```

Now, any queries on `location` will also be very fast: `db.users.find({location:"India"});`

- If your collection grows large, by large I mean, even with indexing you are not satisfied, you need to [**shard your collection**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) (partition) across multiple machines. Sharding is a topic that requires a whole new session on its own, so you need to go through a tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB allows you to create indexes on fields which contain arrays. In that case, each entry in the arrays will be indexed separately. So when you do:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({Sports:1});
```

you can do

```
db.users.find({Sports:"Federer"});
```

and you will get all users which have that value anywhere in the `Sports` array with an index-only query.

Comment: Does this takes care of performance? Cause there are going to billions of users in the system.